# Specifying a single class to check

Tags: revapi

Is it possible to use revapi's maven plugin to check against a single class?

From what I've seen in the docs, and from what I've already tried, it seems it's only possible to check agains a GAV artifact.

Is there anyway to accomplish this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question, this can be done by configuring the java-api extension with:

```
<filter>
   <classes>
      <regex>false</regex>
      <include><item>org.example.ReloadMessage</item></include>
   </classes>
</filter>
```